# Has Somebody used struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.4.1.jar on NETBEANS for Struts2 and Spring?

Tags: spring, plugins, struts2, netbeans-7

Has anyone tried this? How did you do it? I don't have a pom.xml on my project. Could I insert the values of pom.xml on my other xml like web.xml?  I want to use this because I tried just to insert the spring3 library into my struts2 but it seams it don't work unless I'm gonna use the context.getbean("xxxxx")?  I want to start from here again using that plugin.

POM.xml as I searched the net is for Maven? I don't know how to use maven. I am using the normal ones. I think it is ANT.

Comment: I had search the net on looking for that plugin for ANT build. And I could not find any. Why the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing i must say you that do not try to go this way and managing depedencies is too hard and can leads to a lot of conflicts.

You can look in to the dependencies you need for Struts2 Spring plugin inside the [pom.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/struts/struts2/tags/STRUTS_2_3_4_1/plugins/spring/pom.xml?view=markup) defined in the plugin.

You will find a placeholder namely `<version>${struts2.springPlatformVersion}</version>` which is being defined at core [pom.xml](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/struts/struts2/tags/STRUTS_2_3_4_1/pom.xml?view=markup)

Using maven is too easy and will hardly take any time for you to get started but it will take away a lot of manually work for you

Comment: So you advice me that, i will not use spring3? and just the plugin itself? I want the injection style in which you just declare the object as a variable. Car car. Then it is already injected and not using context.getbean. @umesh Awasthi

Comment: @toksis:struts2-spring plugin will only work as a bridge for you which means struts2 internal injection will be done by spring and not s2 internal `objectFacotry`.you need to place Spring3 jars in order for this plugin to work and you can do anything else as per your choice

Comment: Ah, okay no wonder my config don not inject automatically when i do a A a; initialization. Damn, I thought spring is easy. But when you do a cyclic uses of your class, it is very difficult. :)

Comment: With this, probably there is no plugin like this for ant. Better read maven now...

Comment: @toksis:you can even use ant with Maven, it provide its way to integrate your build script :)

Comment: Wow! and as i see now Pom.xml is very powerful. It automates everything like dowloading classpath (dependencies) plugins etc :)

Comment: Thank you.. I had tried the example below and finished it.

http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-integration-example/